# Creating and populating a composite primary key where each part of the composite PK references different tables as a foriegn key

Tags: mysql

I am building a database to house my movie info and all movies have more than one genre so I'm trying to solve the many to many problem with a link table. I am having trouble populating the link table to my movies and Genre tables. The table is the `Movie_Genre` table and both `GenreID` and `MovieID` are the composite primary key for that table. Each part (GenreID and MovieID) are also foreign keys for different tables. I'm having trouble populating this table with the correct values from the other tables. Here is my test script.

```
Create Database Test;

Use Test;

Create Table Movies ( MovieID INT AUTO_INCREMENT Primary key, TiTel
Varchar(255) ) AUTO_INCREMENT=100;

Insert into Movies VALUES (TiTel, 'HellBoy'),  (TiTel, 'Horrible
Bosses');

Create Table Genre (GenreID INT Auto_increment Primary key, Genre
VARCHAR(10));

Insert Into Genre Values (Genre,'Action'),  (Genre,'Adventure'), 
(Genre,'Si-Fi'),  (Genre,'Horrer'),  (Genre,'Fantacey'), 
(Genre,'Thriller'),  (Genre,'Comedy'),  (Genre,'Crime');

Create Table Movie_Genre ( MovieID INT , GenreID INT,  CONSTRAINT
FOREIGN KEY (MovieID) REFERENCES Movies(MovieID),  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN
KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre(GenreID),  Primary key
(MovieID,GenreID));

Insert into Movie_Genre  Value( MovieID = Movies(MovieID)),
     (GenreID = Genre(GenreID));
```

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: the fields of the Movie_Genre table are not being populated with the values from the other two tables (Movies and Genre)